# Prove by induction or strong induction that $a_n > (3/2)^{n-2}$ for positive integers

Tags: induction, solution-verification

Here the sequence is defined by $a_1=1,a_2=2$, and $a_{k+1}=a_{k}+a_{k-1},\,\forall k\geq2$.

---

Stuck on this proof, this is what I have so far
    Proof:
    Basis step $(n=3): 2+1 \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{1}$
        Assume for any arbitrary integer $k \geq 3, a_k \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{k-2}$
        Need to show that $a_{k+1} \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{k-1}$
         $a_{k+1} = a_k + a_{k-1}$
         $ (\frac{3}{2})^{k-2} + a_{k-1} \geq (\frac{3}{2})^{k-1}$
        $ (\frac{3}{2})^{k-2} + (\frac{3}{2})^{k-3}$

Comment: You haven't said what $a_k$ is.

Comment: it is a good idea to show what you have tried, but before that you should state the problem precisely. It is not clear what the question is.

Comment: $$(\frac32)^{k-2}+(\frac32)^{k-3}=(\frac32)^{k-3}\times\frac52=(\frac32)^{k-3}\times\frac{10}4>(\frac32)^{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Base case: n = 2 holds.

Assume $a_{k} > \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{k-2} $ for all $k \leq n$.

Then $a_{n + 1} = a_{n} + a_{n -1} > \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{n-2} + \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{n-3} = \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{n-2} \left( \frac{3 + 2}{3} \right) = \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{n-2} \cdot \frac{10}{6} > \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{n-2} \cdot \frac{9}{6} = \left (\frac{3}{2} \right) ^{(n +1)-2}$.